# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ?tab=month

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, selector

I placed bootstrap tabs on my page, and is trying to active one dynamically from js. Here's an example:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="?tab=day">Hot</a></li>
<li><a href="?tab=week">Week</a></li>
<li><a href="?tab=month">Month</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
    $(function () {
      $('.nav-tabs a[href="\\?tab\\=month"]').tab('show');
    });
</script>
```

But I always got:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression; ?tab=month

from jQuery (v1.7.1).

**Edit:**
I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4wNa/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

show() tries to active both the tab and its content, but the value of href "?tab=month" is not valid for jQuery to select the content.

My workaround is:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="?tab=day" data-target="#">Hot</a></li>
<li><a href="?tab=week" data-target="#">Week</a></li>
<li><a href="?tab=month" data-target="#">Month</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
$(function () {
  $('.nav-tabs a[href="?tab=month"]').tab('show');
});
```

Comment: I was having a similar issue because I did not have `data-target="#"` on my tabs as I was using an alternate method (`AngularJS`) to render the view content. This helped highlight this problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can select in using contains selector,

```
$('.nav-tabs a[href*="month"]')
```

But I can't find any option in jquery ui tabs like `.Tab('show')`

Comment: I got the same error "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ?tab=month", strange.